# Statistical Sampling for Tasks With Different Complexities

Tags: sampling

We have contractors submitting tasks of different complexities (High/Medium/Low) and we would like to audit them. Considering the auditing resource availability, we have to sample the submitted tasks and perform auditing.

I am planning to adopt "ISO 2859-1: Sampling procedures for inspection by attributes" and use the corresponding tables for sample size & AQL selection. My understanding is that choosing the level (Level 1, 2 or 3) will determine the sample size & AQL(1%,1.5%,2.5% etc.) will determine the acceptance/rejection limits.

From a quick calculation, choosing Level 1 for all complexity levels will be within our resource capacity constraint. However, I am worried whether it increases the risk for 'High' complexity tasks by auditing very low (~5%) of them. On the other side, choosing Level 2 will result in auditing decent number of' High' complexity tasks (>10%) but the over all audits required will be beyond our resource capacity.

I am wondering whether it makes sense to go for Level 2 inspection for 'High' complexity tasks and Level 1 inspection for 'Medium/Low' complexity tasks. Similarly opt for  a stricter AQL (say 1%) for 'High' & a liberal AQL (2.55 or  5%) for 'Medium/Low' ones.

Please let me know your thoughts and suggestions. Thank you